# Google map api call not fetching data

Tags: node.js, express, google-maps, react-google-maps-api

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Client } = require('@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js');

const googleMapsClient = new Client({apiKey:"myGoogleApiKey"});


app.use(express.json());


app.get('/calculate-route', async (req, res) => {
  const fromLocation = "Galle, Sri Lanka";
  const toLocation = "Ella, Sri Lanka";
  try {
    const directionsResponse = await googleMapsClient.directions({
      params: {
        origin: fromLocation,
        destination: toLocation,
        mode: 'walking' 
      },
      timeout: 1000,
    });

    res.json(directionsResponse.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error calculating route:', error.response.data);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to calculate route' });
  }
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

i am new to node and express. i need to fetch direction data from googles map api and i encounter a problem while fetching the data saying

`{"error":"Failed to calculate route"}`

I tried to run  `http://localhost:3001/calculate-route` in my local browser to check whether im getting the desired data. but in response i get `{"error":"Failed to calculate route"}`

i need to data as an object that contains the routes and the steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Map API call needs an API KEY,

##### Enabled Map Directions API

[image]

##### Get API Key

[image]

##### API Test by Postman

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?destination=Ella, Sri Lanka&origin=Galle, Sri Lanka&mode=walking&key=[Your API Key]
```

[image]

##### Demo code

Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Client } = require('@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js');

const googleMapsClient = new Client();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/calculate-route', async (req, res) => {
    const fromLocation = "Galle, Sri Lanka";
    const toLocation = "Ella, Sri Lanka";
    const apiKey = "Your API Key"; // Replace with your actual API key
    try {
        const directionsResponse = await googleMapsClient.directions({
            params: {
                origin: fromLocation,
                destination: toLocation,
                mode: 'walking',
                key: apiKey
            },
            timeout: 1000,
        });

        res.json(directionsResponse.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error calculating route:', error.response.data);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to calculate route' });
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install @googlemaps/google-maps-services-js express
```

##### Run server

```
node server.js
```

##### Access it

```
http://localhost:3001/calculate-route
```

##### Result

[image]